# Keyboard volume control with Logitech and Windows 10/11

Tags: windows, keyboard

When I listen to music, I often change the volume with the keys on my Logitech wireless keyboards. I have 2 different models of Logitech wireless keyboards, one on Win 10 and the other on Win 11, that have the same problem where if I hit the volume button multiple times, it changes the amount it adjusts the volume by.

It starts out at increments of 2%, then it apparently goes to 10% after 3-5 rapid presses, including when I hold the button as the first button press. To be clear, the percentage doesn't change while the button is held, just that holding the button doesn't seem to prevent the percentage change in subsequent presses/taps.

For example, if I'm turning down the volume from 50% to 20%, I hold the button down until it's under 30%, then repeatedly (and quickly) tap the same button until it's at the target 20%. However, I often end up muting the volume after just a few taps when it changes the the adjustment amount. The last time this happened, I was at 26%, then I noticed 4% right before the music cut out completely. (Update on 5/11: I managed to see that the percentage is actually 10%.)

Experimenting with it some, it seems to only happen when reducing the volume. I can't seem to get it to happen with increasing the volume. That kind of makes sense, since you don't want to blow out your ears by increasing it too fast.

Also, if I increase the pause between taps, even if it's only once, the percentage doesn't change. So basically, if I do Morse code with the down volume, it stays at a constant 2% drop in volume. And if I tap the button slow and steady, it also stays at 2%. However, if I keep a steady and quick tapping, the percentage switches to 10%.

I'm not sure if this is a Logitech setting or a Windows one. I don't appear to have any Logitech software on my Win 11 machine, except for the driver.

I've looked through volume controls and accessibility controls to figure this out, but no luck. Most of my online research comes up with trying to fix volume buttons that don't work, but my buttons do work, they just change their actions while I'm using them. I also came up with using `Fn` button combos to change the volume, which I don't need due to having working volume buttons. I found a few articles that say to download software to change the amount of volume steps or change the percent from 2% to 1%, but I'm fine with a 2% change, I just don't want the percent to change while I'm using the button.

In case any of this matters, I'm using the Logitech unifying receiver along with a wireless trackball. One keyboard is a K800 (currently on the Win 11 machine) and the other is a K520 (on Win 10). The trackballs on both machines are both M570.

So how do I prevent the volume control/whatever from changing the value of each keypress as I press the volume keys?

Update:
I've swapped my K520 to the Win 11, due to a sticking key on the other keyboard, and it also has the same issue. I figured it would, but I thought I'd test it and mention it here, anyway.

Comment: Not something I know about.  However, the volume buttons on keyboards produce their own scan codes.  They are their own buttons, just like the A, CTRL, F1, etc.  This means Windows itself is what is interpreting the volume buttons.  So its a setting in Windows that needs to change.

Comment: @Keltari, thanks for the info! That narrows things down a bit, since it's evidently not related to the brand, model, or type (wired vs wireless) of the keyboards. Now I kind of wish I had a wired keyboard that had volume buttons to verify if it has the same issue, but I'm not too worried about it.